# Чтения/запись c модуля подключенного к Android через /dev/ttyS2

Tags: android, uart

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой чтения и записи через /dev/ttyS2. Кажется, перерыл весь интернет, но ничего не нашёл. Модуль и аппарат на Android связываются через UART. Права Root на устройстве есть.

Необходимо с помощью приложения управлять модулем. Может быть есть возможность с помощью команд Linux. Попробовал реализовать так:

```
  prompt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.prompt);


    //String[] command = {"df", "-h", "/"};
    //String[] command = {"su","root","chmod", "777", "/dev/ttyS2", "&&", "less", "<","/dev/ttyS2"};
    //String[] command = {"su","root","chmod", "777", "/dev/ttyS2", "&&", "od", "-x", "<","/dev/ttyS2"};
    //String[] command = {"su","root","chmod", "777", "/dev/kulck", "&&", "less","/dev/kulck"};
    //String[] command = {"su","root","chmod", "777", "/dev/ttyS2", "&&","tail", "-f","/dev/ttyS2"};
    //String[] command = {"stty", "-speed", "19200","<","/dev/ttyS2"};
    //String[] command = {"less", "/dev/kulck"};
        String[] command = {"tail", "-f","/dev/ttyS2"};
        //String[] command = {"ls", "-s", "/dev"};

        StringBuilder cmdReturn = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                cmdReturn.append((char) c);
                prompt.setText(cmdReturn.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Надо угадать проблему? В любом случае проверяйте наличие сигнала осциллом, потом - параметры порта: скорость, биты данных и стопов, четность.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов добавил немного информации.